# PCB Design: When having a power plane, should I only be doing vias or also route?

Tags: power, pcb, pcb-design, routing, via

Is it some times relevant to also make the routing between two nodes that are close to each other? Or is it always sufficient to just have vias?

The same question for something other than power, such a signal connected to another plane with e.g. a polygon on the other plane?

[image: Connection]

Comment: Why have a dog and bark yourself? Why squander all that real estate on a power plane, and then track on other planes? There are very few instances where a power plane is a good use of resources. If you have a choice between power and ground planes, with tracks 'stealing' across the ground, or a good ground plane with power tracked along with the signals, then go for the latter every time.

Comment: If TP5 is a through-hole test point, then the via is definitely not needed. The through hole itself provides excellent connection to the +5V plane, unless for some reason the plane is absent under TP5. Personally, in the example you have shown, I would not use the trace. I would let the plane carry the current.

Comment: I agree with Neil that solid ground plane is important, but I am willing to route VCC or multiple VCC's on analog and low-speed digital boards rather than dedicate planes to them. But that doesn't seem to be what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

Usually if there is a plane, I would not route a redundant trace in addition to the plane in normal circumstances.

There ARE cases where it might be done. I don't want to confuse you. So if the following doesn't make sense just ignore it. Your example does not seem to warrant redundant traces.

Sometimes you may route a ground trace from a current shunt (along with the signal from the other side of the shunt) to a current sense amplifier rather than use the ground plane. This is because the signal from the current shunt is very low amplitude, and the amplifier gain will amplify any voltage noise that couples in. So you route from the shunt to the amplifier almost like a differential pair.

If you have very large currents, it may be advantageous to route them on multiple layers from point to point to lower the resistance. But in this case you would use a very wide trace or a fill with many vias. This would be the kind of thing you might see when you get to multiple Amps as opposed to 1 Amp and below.

Sometimes in switching power supplies, there may be a ground fill on a signal layer where the input and output capacitors are tied. This is an effort to keep high switching currents off of the actual ground plane. This fill will still be tied to ground with vias. But the hope is to avoid creating voltage gradients on the actual ground plane as current sloshes back and forth between input and output capacitors. The fill is kind of like an express lane for the high currents. The normal digital or analog currents flow on the ground plane, unbothered by the switcher currents.

That is all I can think of at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your specific example:

[image]

TP5 is already a hole, so via #1 is useless.

If TP5 is just a test point, then keeping via #2 mostly depends on routing convenience. If you want to route vertical traces in the space where trace #3 would be, then remove trace #3 and use via #2. If via forces you to move a component to make room for it, then it's fine to remove it and use trace #3 instead.

However, considering via #2 and TP5: if one of them is a thru-hole pad or via carrying high/noisy current then due to via impedance being non-zero, a noise voltage will exist between the top of the pad on toplayer and the plane. If the other pad/via is a sensitive signal (I see a VREF on your pic) then it is a good idea to give it its own via to the plane so it doesn't share a common impedance with the noisy signal.

For example when a chip has AGND and DGND pins, that's meant to reduce common impedance coupling between the two, so better go all the way and give each its own via. Generally it's a bad idea to pick up an analog reference or ground from vias used by chips' power/GND pin, or vias from a nearby decoupling cap that carry AC current as the cap does its decoupling job.